# Changing DNS provider

Tags: dns-hosting, dns-zone

probably my question had been answered elsewhere but I could not find it yet.

One of our clients is about change DNS provider to our (also hosted) DNS provider.

They provided the zone file.
I have created a zone (toto.com) for them added A and MX records.

What I am worried about to see some NS records like

```
hq              IN NS   dns1.learndirect.co.uk.
hq              IN NS   dns2.learndirect.co.uk. 
hq              IN NS   ns3.learndirect.net.
hq              IN NS   ns4.learndirect.net.

dr              IN NS   dns1.learndirect.co.uk. 
dr              IN NS   dns2.learndirect.co.uk. 
dr              IN NS   ns4.learndirect.net. 
dr              IN NS   ns3.learndirect.net.
```

I am not sure what to do with them.

When I dig them I do not get IP address but a SOA record.

```
... ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
hq.toto.com.        1800    IN  SOA dns1.learndirect.co.uk. TOTO.hostmaster.toto.com. 2016083100 10800 3600 864000 1800 ...
```

I can not add NS record to my hosted provider management interface anyway.

I suppose they are there for reason, but how can I doublecheck it?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the start of a subdomain record... hq.toto.com is a subdomain, and it will use those nameservers...

Answer (score -1):

If you get SOA record as response, this mean that there is no other record for this host (subdomain).

Comment: Thanks, in that case I do not need to worry about those when transferring the zone because they don't convey any services.